# Why is ffmpeg not showing SSIM results when I do -tune ssim?

Tags: ffmpeg, ssim

I'm trying to benchmark for SSIM in FFmpeg. If I do this

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf vidstabtransform,unsharp=5:5:0.8:3:3:0.4 -psnr -ssim 1 output.mp4

...
[libx264 @ 0x7fe85b007600] SSIM Mean Y:0.9898484 (19.935db)
[libx264 @ 0x7fe85b007600] PSNR Mean Y:47.666 U:54.805 V:54.799 Avg:49.010 Global:48.071 kb/s:2595.20
```

I get the SSIM and PSNR in the command line. If I add the -tune, I don't get these results anymore. What is happening?

Comment: example -tune full command line and uncut console output?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! If you still want the result to appear, you should do `-tune psnr -psnr -tune ssim -ssim`.

Comment: The last -tune overrides the first, so your commandline will *only* tune for ssim, and then display PSNR *and* SSIM.